UI Tween incorrect Positioning, Luau Roblox Studio Ui
I've been trying a lot of ways, it was way worse, it made the pawns disappear and then appear only at the tween complete, so yeah, but now its simpler, so can you help me, I've been reading through dev forums and other peoples issues, but I cant find solutions till now, I'm still trying, help would be appericated.
Here's my entire code of this part of the issue.
local SGUI = game.StarterGui
local frame = SGUI.ScreenGui.Background.OutlineFrame.InnerFrame
local theDock = frame.Parent.Parent.PlayerDock
local thePawn = theDock.Player1
local currentBoxOfPawn = thePawn.CurrentBox.Value
local ts = game:GetService("TweenService")

local isMoving = thePawn.Moving

if isMoving.Value then return end

if currentBoxOfPawn == "000" then
    currentBoxOfPawn = "001"

    local oldPos = thePawn.Position
    local oldSize = thePawn.Size

    isMoving.Value = true
    thePawn.Visible = false

    local newPawn = thePawn:Clone()
    newPawn.Visible = true
    newPawn.Parent = frame.Parent.Parent -- Set to frame.Parent to keep it visible

    local function getAbsolutePositionAndSize(guiObject)
        local absPos = guiObject.AbsolutePosition
        local absSize = guiObject.AbsoluteSize
        return UDim2.new(0, absPos.X, 0, absPos.Y), UDim2.new(0, absSize.X, 0, absSize.Y)
    end

    local oldAbsPos, oldAbsSize = getAbsolutePositionAndSize(thePawn)
    newPawn.Position = oldAbsPos
    newPawn.Size = oldAbsSize

    -- Ensure thePawn is parented to the correct frame
    local newParent = frame:FindFirstChild(currentBoxOfPawn)
    if newParent then
        thePawn.Parent = newParent
    else 
        isMoving.Value = false
        return
    end

    local newAbsPos, newAbsSize = getAbsolutePositionAndSize(thePawn)
    
    local movement = ts:Create(newPawn, TweenInfo.new(1, Enum.EasingStyle.Linear, Enum.EasingDirection.InOut), {
        Position = newAbsPos,
        Size = newAbsSize
    })
    movement:Play()

    movement.Completed:Connect(function()
        isMoving.Value = false
        thePawn.Visible = true
        newPawn:Destroy()
    end)
end

To explain, the Checkered is consistent of boxes for each white or black box, aka a frame, and the frame has a UIGridLayout to allow for multiple pawns at once without collision, and so, that causes a lot of issues when getting the correct position and size as you probably know, that's all. its a little down not in the correct place as the real pawn is in.
And there's a video attached to show the problem
https://imgur.com/a/QQyVk92
Btw, this system is supposed to be used for moving from one box to another and so and so, and I'm planning to add a more smooth way of up then down to the location so I need it to be clear and understandable to allow for change and use so its confusing me a lot.
That should clarify the point of this system, it is NOT like chess, its a one by one box game, no need to explain entirely, just I'm trying to make it so there's a event/code to move any chip/pawn from one place to another box without player input.
Thank you.

I tried shifting my attention here and there and kept trying—I still do—but the rest is also to make clear the purpose of this code, which serves you and others. I hope that clarifies things. I'm not giving up responsibility, only wanting to know if there's a solution for why it keeps occurring. I'm good but not the best at Luau, but in the case that I need to calculate the Absolute Size and Position in UI, I haven't done before. Thanks.

Try editing your Position and Size variables manually while creating the tween. Maybe the size and position data you are getting from getAbsolutePositionAndSize(guiObject) is wrong. I don't see any problem besides that.
